# How to convert Html nested list <ul></ul> to javascript Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

I have a list structure as below, I want to convert this to a javascript Array

I have nested Ul Li elements which are used to create menu structure.

I am creating the HTML list from server side. Which I want to give as a item source of a Jquery menu Items

refer [Menu](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu)

```
<ul> 
<li data-command="btnCmdClick1">        
    Menu1
</li>
<li data-command="btnCmdClick2">        
    Menu2
</li>
<li data-command="btnCmdClick3">        
    Menu3
</li>
<li data-command="btnCmdClick4">
    <ul> Sub Menu1          
        <li data-command="btnCmdClick5">
            Menu1
        </li>
        <li data-command="btnCmdClick6">
                <ul> Sub Sub Menu           
                    <li data-command="btnCmdClick7">
                        Menu1
                    </li>
                    <li data-command="btnCmdClick8">
                        Menu2
                    </li>
                    <li data-command="btnCmdClick9">
                        Menu3
                    </li>           
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li data-command="btnCmdClick10">
            Menu3
        </li>           
    </ul>
</li>   
<li data-command="btnCmdClick11">
        <ul> Sub Menu2          
            <li data-command="btnCmdClick12">
                Menu1
            </li>
            <li data-command="btnCmdClick13">
                Menu2
            </li>
            <li data-command="btnCmdClick14">
                Menu3
            </li>           
        </ul>
</li>
```

I want Array Exactly like this

```
var items = {
            "btnCmdClick1": { "name": "Menu1", "icon": "" },
            "btnCmdClick2": { "name": "Menu2", "icon": "" },
            "btnCmdClick3": { "name": "Menu3", "icon": "" },
            "btnCmdClick4": {
                "name": "Sub Menu1",
                "items": {
                    "btnCmdClick5": { "name": "Menu1" , "icon": "" },
                    "btnCmdClick6": {
                        "name": "Sub Sub Menu",
                        "items": {
                            "btnCmdClick7": { "name": "Menu1", "icon": "" },
                            "btnCmdClick8": { "name": "Menu2", "icon": "" },
                            "btnCmdClick9": { "name": "Menu3", "icon": "" }
                        }
                    },
                    "btnCmdClick10": { "name": "Menu3", "icon": "" }
                }
            },
            "btnCmdClick11": {
                "name": "Sub Menu2",
                "items": {
                            "btnCmdClick12": { "name": "Menu1", "icon": "" },
                            "btnCmdClick13": { "name": "Menu2", "icon": "" },
                            "btnCmdClick14": { "name": "Menu3", "icon": "" }
                }
            }
        };
```

Please Help`
Actually Implementing this [Right Click Context menu](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo/sub-menus.html)

Comment: What have you tried ? Looking at `jquery.each` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ is a good start.

Comment: You need to have a look at obtaining JXON from DOM tree http://mdn.beonex.com/en/JXON.html

Comment: @rafh & redu thanks for hint i will check this out. Using Jquery.each i need to write some funtion. Although i am looking for any other short solutions